# How to input multiple data in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model like this:

```
class EventLocationTime(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=_("event"))
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, verbose_name=_("location"))
    start = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("start time"))
    end = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("end time"))
```

and I use django admin for data entry. I want to select an event and a location and enter multiple `(start,end)` for one `(event, location)` pair.

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use [Django Import / Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to be able to import data to `EventLocationTime` model from an external file. Then you could create an Excel, CSV, JSON or whichever format you prefer, with all the data you need, and import it to django admin.